# What language/tool can I use to generate a dynamic 3d model on a website

Tags: web, 3d, 3d-model

I am developing some sort of browser (war) game, in which player can have a village with certain different buildings (watchtowers, walls etc..) As an overview I want to generate a small 3d model of the village with little interactivity (maybe they can click on a building in the village and it will display info about this building). It should be dynamic (they can upgrade these buildings, and I would want them to change after an upgrade) and depend on values in the database. What tool or programming language is best to use for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like [Three.js](http://threejs.org/) or [BabylonJS](http://www.babylonjs.com/).